# How to upgrade the Android app developed in Android version 2.2 to higher version

Tags: android

Is it possible to upgrade Android app developed in Android version 2.2 to be competible to higher Android version. I like to upgrade to Android version 4.3 Jelly Bean.
The problem is my ADT installed is for Android version 4.3 Jelly Bean. Using Eclipse from that ADT version can't debug Android App developed with Android version 2.2.
What could be the problem and how to solve?
Thanks

Comment: Your 2.2 app should already be compatible with Android 4.3. Android is backward compatible (although, that won't give you all the goodies that come with Android 4.3). What do you mean debugging doesn't work? Do you mean to say you don't have the source file installed for 2.2, so debug mode won't let you step through that code?

Comment: Yeah the problem is the program doesn't stop at breakpoints running in the device.

Comment: I can run the program in the device but can't stop at breakpoints. What could be the problem?

Comment: I have android:debuggable="false" and have to change to true. Thanks

Comment: Who downvoted me, any reason why you did that?

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok, I get it now. Assuming that you're not getting an error in your logcat that prevents you from reaching your first breakpoint. Assuming that you're debugging the application (not just running it). And assuming that your application tag in your manifest contains the attribute android:debuggable="true".

There are two options. You can try resetting the target api level to 4.3 in your manifest and in the build file, and then deal with changing the apis that are (possibly) giving you errors. There are menu commands in Eclipse that can help with that.

You could try downloading an older api level (as old as 2.2, or older than 2.2. That you can still find the source with, that you can attach it to your Eclipse). I've got to warn you that last option might be difficult (because around that time, the attaching of source file used to be a manual process, not an automatic one, and when the automatic process came along, it broke the manual process of attaching source files).

Comment: I have android:debuggable="false" and have to change to true. Thanks